# Why do we use the article 'a' when referring to 100 items? But we don't use it when referring to any other plural count?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, countable-nouns

**Edit Note**:

This question has been linked to these questions about using an article before adjectives modifying numbers. This question here has nothing to do with adjectives at all:

- [Indefinite articles used with plural nouns: It was AN amazing TWO DAYS](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days)
- [Indefinite article in the "An [adjective] [number] [plural noun]" construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/indefinite-article-in-the-an-adjective-number-plural-noun-construction)

**The question**

Why do we use the article 'a' when referring to 100, but not when referring to any other plural counting?

Here's an example:

> I saw a hundred birds today.

But when talking about other count that 100, we don't use 'a' because it's plural:

> - I saw ninety-nine birds today.
> - I saw two birds today.
> - I saw two thousand birds.
> - I saw seventy-five birds.

Is there a grammatical or historical explanation?

Comment: This also aplies to other round multiples of 10 above 100 that have special names: a thousand birds, a million birds, a billion birds, and all the other "-illion" words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Indefinite articles used with plural nouns: It was AN amazing TWO DAYS](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days)* Also see *[Indefinite article in the “An |adjective| |number| |plural noun|” construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9933)*.

Comment: @choster the suggested original questions use the indefinite article before attributive adjectives,  such as *amazing*, *wonderful*, *incredible* etc. Not bare numbers, otherwise we would all be saying " We saw a two endangered birds today"

Comment: a dozen, a score(?)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/why-should-i-say-one-hundred-when-hundred-seems-enough

Comment: *"But we don't use it when referring to any other plural count?"* Like *a dozen*, *a thousand*, *a million*, *a stone* (ch. Br.)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Can you give any examples of "stone" being used as a plural count? I'm only familiar with it meaning a weight...

Comment: @psmears: No, you're right, we'd only say "a stone" when referring to just the one stone. It's stands for multiple pounds (14 of them), but yeah, "a stone" is a singular, not a plural, so it shouldn't be in the list above, just like "a ton" (or "a tonne") wouldn't be in that list.

Comment: @choster Hold on, there's no mention of any adjectives in this question!!!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed. There's not an adjective insight in this question. It has nothing to do with the linked to questions at all, even remotely. Am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 34):

*a* is replacing *one*.

That is, in the following pairings, both options are legitimate:

> I saw one hundred [and] forty-seven birds today.<sup>1</sup> 
> I saw a hundred [and] forty-seven birds today.<sup>1</sup>
>
> I earned one million dollars.
> I earned a million dollars.

Preferences for one or the other may vary.  To me, using *one* sounds more precise than *a*, so that would influence my usage: in the first pairing, "one" sounds better to me, while "a" sounds better in the second, unless I was trying to emphasize that I earned *exactly* one million dollars.

Regardless, either option is legitimate because *a* is a synonym for *one*.  The reason your other examples don't work is that they don't start with *one*.

---

1. The use of "and" in the first pairing above varies based on region (US vs. UK) and speaker preference.  See [How do you correctly say large numbers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/37958/53711)

Comment: Also worth noting that this is common in other languages where the indefinite article is either exactly or a close cognate for the number 1: _uno_ vs. _un_ / _una_ (Spanish), _eins_ vs. _ein_ / _eine_ /.... (German), etc.

Answer (score 8):

"Hundred" is *not* plural! It is singular. You have *one* hundred. Hence the "a" ( or "one").

Consider:

> I saw a hundred birds today.
>   I saw two hundred birds today.
>   I saw three hundred birds today.

Also:

> I saw a dozen birds today.
>   I saw twelve birds today.