# Why do the words hundred & thousand require "a" before them, where ten & ten thousand do not?

Tags: grammar

Not much to say here that was not said in the title... I'm wondering about adding "a" before a quantifier, and what are the rules for it. Is somehow ten considered to be plural, where hundred / thousand considered to be a group of 100 / 1000, and as a group it's singular?

Comment: The indefinite article is used in place of *one* there. "One thousand" and "a thousand" are equivalent.

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275747/why-do-we-use-the-article-a-when-referring-to-100-items-but-we-dont-use-it-w

Comment: “Hundred” is kind of just the “00” part. You still need to say how many of them you are referring to. “Ten” refers to both digits of “10”.